# $\lim_{n\to\infty} U_n/n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

for $U_1=3/2$, $U_{n+1}=(n+1)^2/(U_n+1)$. Prove that there exists $$\lim_{n\to\infty} U_n/n$$ and find it

Please help me.. I thought it sounds pretty good when we tried to limit two side of $U_n$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this for a course in analysis or calculus? You have to provide us with the background information and attempts if you want any help.

Comment: What have you tired? What method does your textbook suggest for recurring sequences?

Comment: #F.Conrad I don't know how to get it right and also the code of each method.. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's a bit harsh on OP: to prove lower and upper bounds for $U_n$, in the simplest case $n-a\le U_n\le n+b$ and by induction, doesn't sound like a bad idea, though I didn't get that right, either. So I had to come up with something better, but I'd like to see the textbook suggesting that. There are no standard methods for non-linear recurrences, after all.
Here we go: let $$U_n=\frac{n\,w_n}{w_{n+1}}.$$ A little algebra now gives $$w_{n+2}=\frac{w_{n+1}+n\,w_n}{n+1},$$ and this can be transformed into $$(n+1)\,(w_{n+2}-w_{n+1})=-n\,(w_{n+1}-w_n).$$ Thus, $$n\,(w_{n+1}-w_n)=(-1)^{n-1}\,(w_2-w_1),$$ and finally $$w_n=w_1+(w_2-w_1)\,\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}.$$ Remembering $U_1=w_1/w_2$, we arrive at
$$U_n=n\,\frac{U_1+(1-U_1)\,\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}}{U_1+(1-U_1)\,\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}}.$$
So we can see that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{U_n}{n}=1,$$ it doesn't depend on $U_1$.